# Faster membership test (numpy.isin too slow)

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm working on a real time image processing project and there is a requirement for changing some parameters. The exact details are not important, so I'll just stick to the relevant part:

I have two Numpy arrays, one of which is a list of index values (it has repeated indices) and another one is a list of valid indices.

I tried `np.intersect1D`, however that removes the duplicate index values, so then I tried `np.isin` and `np.in1d`, both of which take around 900ms to finish.

```
mask = np.isin(index_array,validRange)
new_index_array = index_array[mask]
new_coeff_array = coeff_array[mask]
```

I also tried using a set and a dictionary as look up tables for membership test, but they too were rather slow (around 1.2seconds).

As a last effort, I implemented a binary search algorithm in Cython, which operated over the sorted version of `validRange` but for some reason it would crash the kernel randomly (with the exact same inputs, it would fail at different points). Admittedly the arrays I'm working with are rather large (index array has 4,706,878 elements and valid range has 527,076 elements), but even so, intersect1D manages to finish (closer to 400ms).

Even though this is not a common operation, stopping a real time system for around 900ms while the settings are being updated is not really acceptable.

Is there any way to speed up this process to be closer to the 300 to 400ms time of the intersect1d, without removing the duplicate elements? I looked around google and tried a few different suggestions, but they didn't really improve things.

P.S. I know some want to comment about using `np.where(x>y)` but the `validRange` is not continuous and is called that for convenience. Actual values could for example be: [1,2,5,8,15,20,21], so a simple condition can't solve this.

Comment: If timing becomes an issue, Python may not be the right tool.

Comment: that's exactly why I tried using Cython, it runs at native C speed, but gives the convenience of all the existing python packages

Comment: As you appear to be off by a factor of maybe 2-4, you might be able to use multiprocessing and shared memory to use multiple CPU cores. The latest shared memory stuff is seriously fast and many CPUs have 4/8/12 cores nowadays. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: What is the type of the array items? If this is integers, how big are they? Are they bounded? Does the `validRange` change over time? It would be great if you could provide a more complete example representing your application.

Comment: The values are all integer, no need for approximation with floats. The range is bounded between 0 and 857,476 (926*926). validRange does change depending on the selected settings, otherwise it would have been easy to construct it as a boolean array and just use it as a mask, instead of generating a mask from it. Unfortunately to provide a more meaningful example, I have to add A LOT of other code which is not really the focus here, I just want to find members of array A that are also present in array B.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. Could you please show an example input and the exact desired corresponding output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean **lookup table** to compute the result of `np.isin` very quickly since values of `validRange` are relatively-small positive bounded integers. The table can be built very efficiently using **`np.bincount`**. This method is very fast only when the size of `validRange` is significantly smaller than `index_array` which is clearly the case here.

Here is an example:

```py
assert len(validRange) > 0

# Build the lookup table
lut = np.bincount(validRange) > 0
bound = len(lut)

# Pre-filter the invalid ranges and locate the value to check further
# If index_array contains only positive values, 
# then you can just use:  mask = index_array < bound
mask = np.logical_and(index_array >= 0, index_array < bound)
validRangeIdx = np.where(mask)

# Correct the mask by using the very fast LUT
mask[validRangeIdx] = lut[index_array[validRangeIdx]]

new_index_array = index_array[mask]
new_coeff_array = coeff_array[mask]
```

On my machine, this implementation is **between 7 to 32 times faster** than the original implementation regarding the values in both `index_array` and `validRange`.

If you want an even faster code, you can use **Numba** to avoid the creation of the quite-big temporary arrays and **parallelize** the operations easily with it. With all of this, you should be able to enjoy the resulting truly real-time computation.

---

Note that you can use your GPU to speed up the computation even more if needed using CuPy on Nvidia cards or ClPy on other OpenCL-compatible devices. You can do this with a simple `import cupy as np`. Note however that those packages introduces a quite big latency between some computations that may not be great for a real-time computation. Nevertheless, I can reach a **speed up of 150** with CuPy with a GTX-1660S GPU compared to the initial implementation when the computation is put in an iterative loop!

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. I wasn't aware of the bincount method. I also found a trick that works a bit faster: Generating the validRange as a large boolean array which covers all possible values, with the valid indices set to true and the rest set to false(this can be directly used as the lookup table. I have to give props to you for your previous comment which made me think of this solution). This uses more memory but I think is worth the tradeoff because I'm mainly concerned with the speed of the operations (current result is 42ms, very acceptable). Thank you very much.